# SQL Server - SUM(Column) * QtyColumn

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to get the total without returning it in multiple rows (Group BY)?

Example:

Data:

```
ID    Amount   Quantity
1     50       1 
2     50       2
```

```
select sum(Amount) * Quantity, SUM(Quantity) as totalQuantity 
  from tbl
```

I want the results to be in 1 row:

```
total       totalQuantity 
150         3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go

```
SELECT SUM(Amount*Quantity) as total, SUM(Quantity) as totalQuantity
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select sum(Amount * Quantity) as total, 
       sum(Quantity) as totalQuantity
from your_table
```